# Using regex or wildcards in a python loop

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, python-re

I'm tidying up an Excel workbook and I need to find all instances of Microsoft.* - for example Microsoft.Compute and Microsoft.Cdn - and copy them into the column to the left.

I've put this code together but it doesn't like the regex

```
import openpyxl as op
import re

wb = op.load_workbook("original-workbook.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

pattern = re.compile(r'Microsoft.+')

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3):
    if row[1].value in pattern:
        row[0].value = pattern[row[1].value]

wb.save("new-improved-workbook.xlsx")
```

This is the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 're.Pattern' is not iterable
```

I'm sure what I want to do it really simple but it's got me stumped.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pattern is an object holding your compiled regex hence not iterable. You need to call a method such as match or search to get access to groups and iterate over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `TypeError`, I assume that you need to check if the cells on column `B` match `Microsoft*` and then update the corresponding `A` cells. If so, regex doesn't seem *necessary*, you can simply check if the values [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) `Microsoft`.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook("original-workbook.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

# pattern = re.compile(r"Microsoft.+") # uncomment if regex needed

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3):
    if row[1].value and row[1].value.startswith("Microsoft"):
    # if row[1].value and pattern.match(row[1].value): # to fix your code
        row[0].value = row[1].value

wb.save("new-improved-workbook.xlsx")
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Perfect - cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises from the sole fact that you are not utilising the regular expression's library as it is intended. I personally suggest that you have a glimpse over its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), especially if you are going to use it often.

The following modification to the first if statement within the loop is going to ensure first and foremost that the value is valid, in this case not `None`, in a defensive programming manner, since I assume that's how openpyxl deals with missing entries; then it utilises the match method which is applied on a re.Pattern instance, in this case your `pattern` variable, and which takes as a parameter a string, which it tests against the pattern. Alternatively, rather than using the instance-side method you can use the package wide function re.match(), which takes in the pattern and the string which you want to match against it.

```py
import openpyxl as op
import re

wb = op.load_workbook("original-workbook.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]

pattern = re.compile(r'Microsoft.+')

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=3):
    if row[1].value and pattern.match(row[1].value):
        row[0].value = pattern.sub('', row[1].value)

wb.save("new-improved-workbook.xlsx")
```

Comment: Is this an *AI-generated* answer ? Your other answers imply so!  Please, read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1).

Comment: Now what made you assume that, can't people be pedantic in this day and age, and atop of that aspire towards a manner of writing that's influenced by the European trends rather the American modern way of butchering English?